# How to name a FireStore document by date selected from datepicker? (Android - Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to name a FireStore document by a date selected by the user from date picker dialog (**as a String**).

"docRef = db.collection("Time Slots Lists").document( ***user selected date*** )"

The problem is instead of getting a document named for example "22/02/2019"
I get what shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

There is 2 document created (25 and null) then a collection named (02) then a document named (2019) !!

**code:**

```
class ReserveTimeFragment : Fragment() {

private var timeSlotsList: ArrayList<TimeSlot>? = null
private var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
private var mAdapter: TimeSlotAdapter? = null
private var mLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
private var viewHolder: TimeSlotAdapter.TimeSlotViewHolder? = view?.tag as TimeSlotAdapter.TimeSlotViewHolder?


private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

private val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd / MM / yyyy")

private var dateString: String? = null


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reserve_time, container, false)

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewLO)

    pickDate()
    callTimeSlotsList()

    return view
}

**private fun pickDate() {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    var date: String
    val datePick = DatePickerDialog(this.context!!, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, mYear, mMonth, mDay
        ->  
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear)
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay)

        dateTV.text = dateFormat.format(cal.time)
        dateString = dateFormat.format(cal.time)

        Toast.makeText(context!!, "$dateString is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))

    datePick.show()
    datePick.setCancelable(false)
}**

private fun callTimeSlotsList(){

    val docRef = db.collection("Time Slots List").document("$dateString")

    docRef.addSnapshotListener(EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> { documentSnapshot, e ->

        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Time Slots List Listen failed.", e)
            return@EventListener
        }

        if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {

            docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->

                val listObjectFromFB = documentSnapshot.toObject(ListObjectToFireStore::class.java)
                val ListToRVAdaptet = listObjectFromFB?.listToFireStore

                timeSlotsList = ListToRVAdaptet
                buildRecyclerView()

                Log.d(TAG, "FireStore Time Slots List Called Successfully")
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "New Time Slots List Loaded!")

            loadTimeSlotsList()
            buildRecyclerView()
        }
    })
}    
private fun buildRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
    mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context!!)
    mAdapter = TimeSlotAdapter(timeSlotsList!!, context!!, db)

    mRecyclerView!!.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
    mRecyclerView!!.adapter = mAdapter

    viewHolder?.cardview?.setOnClickListener {
    }
}

private fun loadTimeSlotsList() {
    val timeSlotsListToLoad: ArrayList<TimeSlot> = ArrayList()

    timeSlotsListToLoad.add(TimeSlot("07:30", "Available", false, 2))
    timeSlotsListToLoad.add(TimeSlot("08:00", "Available", false, 2))

    val timeSlotsListToFB = ListObjectToFireStore(timeSlotsListToLoad)

    db.collection("Time Slots List").document("$dateString").set(timeSlotsListToFB).addOnSuccessListener {
       Log.w(TAG, "time Slots List Uploaded Successfully")
    }.addOnFailureListener{
        Log.w(TAG, "time Slots List Upload Failed")
    }
    timeSlotsList = timeSlotsListToLoad
}
```

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The / character is a path separator in Firestore.  It can't be part of the name of a document or collection because it has special meaning.  Read the documentation on the [limits of collections, documents and fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields):

> Constraints on collection IDs
>
> - Must be valid UTF-8 characters
> - Must be no longer than 1,500 bytes
> - **Cannot contain a forward slash (/)**
> - Cannot solely consist of a single period (.) or double periods (..)
> - Cannot match the regular expression **.***

Consider removing the slash from the string before using it as a document ID or finding some other way to identify the document.

Comment: I've removed the forward slash, and it did work well, but I still have the null document issue. I think the problem is with the global variable "dateString", is there a way to wait on user input from the date picker dialog and then returns the result depending on the dialog contents. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know. Sounds like a new problem, and a new post to ask the question.

Comment: Thanks, Doug for the help. Regarding the null document, I got rid of it by adding the rest of the code in the date picker "OnDateSetListener" but I don't know if this is the right way to do it.